# In JavaScript, is there a way to make a button/text field combo that will append a blank paragraph with the contents of the text field

Tags: javascript, button, textfield

It also has to make a button next to it that allows me to clear just the text field's contents.

Here's the code I have so far, but I'm completely lost on how to proceed:

```
$(function(){
  var assignmentCount = 0
  $("#assignment").on("click",function(event){
      var task1 = $("#task").val()
      $("p").append("<p id=task>"+task1+"</p>");
      $("p").append("<button id="+assignmentCount+" "+">Complete</button>");
  })
  $("#button").on("click",function(event){
    $("task1").empty()
  })
  $("#clear").on("click",function(event){
      $("p").empty()
  })

  $("#finish").on("click",function(event){
      var completedText = $("#finished").val()
      asdf = completedText+" was completed."
      $("p").append(asdf);
  })
});
```

I don't know how to clear just one line of the appended text, and I'm also kind of new to javascript and code in general

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `<p>` or action items like `<button>` inside `<p>`. Convert it into a `<div>` so that it works. And a few more things that I made change:

1. Changed `<p>` container into `<div>` container to have children `<p>`.
2. Your `id`s are getting repeated, so I updated them to make it work.
3. There's no tag named `task1` so I added a `#` in front to make it an `id`.

```js
$(function() {
  var assignmentCount = 0
  $("#assignment").on("click", function(event) {
    var task1 = $("#task").val()
    $("div").append("<p id='task" + assignmentCount + "'>" + task1 + "</p>");
    $("div").append("<button id=btn" + assignmentCount + " " + ">Complete</button>");
  })
  $("#button").on("click", function(event) {
    $("#task1").empty();
  })
  $("#clear").on("click", function(event) {
    $("div").empty();
  });
  $("#finish").on("click", function(event) {
    var completedText = $("#finished").val()
    asdf = completedText + " was completed."
    $("p").append(asdf);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button id="button">Empty</button>
```